# StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DialogComponent]

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to create a reusable Dialog Box using Kendo Library, but when doing so i get always the below error.

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent ->
>   DialogComponent]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent ->
>   DialogComponent]: NullInjectorError: No provider for DialogComponent!

Here is my component file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  DialogService,
          DialogRef,
          DialogCloseResult } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css']
})
export class DialogComponent {

  constructor( private dialogService: DialogService ) {}

  public open() {
    const dialog = this.dialogService.open({
      title: 'Please confirm',
      content: 'Are you sure?',
      actions: [
        { text: 'No' },
        { text: 'Yes', primary: true }
      ]
    });

    dialog.result.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result instanceof DialogCloseResult) {
        console.log('close');
      } else {
        console.log('action', result);
      }
    });
}
}
```

I tried couple of things but with no luck to get past this error.

[Stackblitz Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frnvji)

Answer (score 1):

Add `import { DialogService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';` in your `app.module.ts`

And `DialogService` in providers array in the same file.

And add `DialogComponent` in exports array in `app.module.ts`